# Getting error when running Cucumber from Jenkins tool

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea

Below error is shown when I run a cucumber framework with Jenkins integration.
Please can anyone answer by seeing this error message.

I am have written code in Java using cucumber framework.
And run through Jenkins integration.

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ thingDynamics ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ thingDynamics ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ thingDynamics ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ thingDynamics ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ thingDynamics ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/target/test-classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.625s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 07 11:28:21 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project thingDynamics: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/testcases/Launch.java:[34,5] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR]
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/utills/SeleniumUtils.java:[98,19] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR]
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/utills/SeleniumUtils.java:[683,30] error: enhanced for loops are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR]
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/testcases/Dashboard.java:[32,5] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR]
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/testcases/PolicyMgmt.java:[26,5] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR]
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /volume1/jenkins/jobs/thingDynamics-automaation/workspace/src/test/java/testcases/AssetMgmt.java:[27,5] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: If you run the same maven command from the command line does it return the same errors? take also a look at this --> https://www.mkyong.com/maven/annotations-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3-maven/